# Plot $g(r) = \int_0^\pi J_0(w\ r)\ \mathrm dw $

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to plot $g(r) = \int_0^\pi J_0(w\ r)\ \mathrm dw $ as a function of $r$, but $g(r)$ at each value of $r$ is an integral of the Bessel function over the the limits of $w$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica can do the symbolic integral, so:

```
g[r_] = Integrate[BesselJ[0, w r], {w, 0, Pi}]
```

> π HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2}, {1, 3/2}, -(1/4) π^2 r^2]

Visualization:

```
Plot[g[r], {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome !!! Thank you much.